# React Native WebView - Open link in external browser only in case of user interaction

Tags: react-native, webview

I have the following WebView component that is used multiple times for various embeds inside news articles

```js
<WebView
    useWebKit={true}
    ref={(ref) => this.webview = ref}
    javaScriptEnabled={true}
    injectedJavaScript={"(" + injectedScript + ")()"}
    onMessage={this.onMessage}
    onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationStateChange}
    {...this.props}
/>
```

and the following navigation state change listener, used for opening links in an external browser

```js
onNavigationStateChange = (event) => {
    this.webview.stopLoading();
    Linking.openURL(event.url);
}
```

The problem is that the navigation change listener doesn't seem capable of differentiating between user interaction and automatic page redirects (which social media embeds will often do). How can I open the link in an external browser ONLY for user interaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know exactly if automatic page redirects trigger click events, but they should not, so you can listen to only `click` events, which I suppose can only be triggered by the user.

```
onNavigationStateChange = (navState) =>
{
    if (navState.navigationType === 'click') {
        // User clicked something
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have thought something similar should be possible, but somehow my `navState` object doesn't contain a `navigationType` property, only something like this: `{ canGoForward: false,
  canGoBack: true,
  loading: true,
  title: 'about:blank',
  url: 'about:blank',
  target: 5 }`

Comment: Apparently it's an older bug for Android that should have been fixed a while ago. I am using the latest versions of `react-native` and `WebView` though.

Comment: Hmm, so it's an Android issue, but should work on iOS... Maybe, would checking against the url work for you? Like `if (navState.url !== 'about:blank') { ... }`?

Comment: Tried that already! But those pesky social media embeds redirect like 100 times and the url is different each time. There is no other programmatic way of knowing which is user interaction. But your answer pointed me in another good direction. Clearly `navigationType` missing from Android is a bug that needs fixing. I will post a bug report on GitHub, so thanks for that!

Comment: Yeah, your solution is correct, it's just a bug right now on Android and hopefully I can get them to have a look at it again.